# Using MPChartLibrary within a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, mpandroidchart

I am working on an Android project and I am trying to implement a Library called MPAndroidChart from https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart.

I am trying to implement it in a fragment but I keep getting an error and I cannot see why.

Below is my activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment chartFragment = new ChartFragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, chartFragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Below is my activities layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Below is my Fragment class

```
public class ChartFragment extends Fragment
{
    private LineChart mChart;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.graph, container, false);



        return v;
    }
}
```

And below is the layout for the fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/lineChart1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

At the moment it crashes when it tries to inflate the view in my OnCreateView function.

The error I am getting is:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.MyCompany.ChartTest/com.MyCompany.ChartTest.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error
>   inflating class com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart

Comment: Somebody named Uncle-Leo had a similar exception see https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/26 ; Clean the library and see if there are different versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list

Comment: Thanks, I've checked the support lib is using the latest version and there's no others being included, and I've deleted my apps build folder and the library modules build folder and rebuilt but still getting the same error

Comment: What happens if you try without the xml ? Are you able to do setContextView(new LineChart(this)); or something similar ?

Comment: I just used your code and it works like a charm which IDE did u use? Have you imported the jar file into your libs folder and added it to the build path using "Add to build path"?

Answer (score 1):

I honestly do not see anything that could be wrong.

The only difference I see between the `Fragments` used in the [**example project**](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/tree/master/MPChartExample) is that they use `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent` for the width and height of the chart.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/lineChart1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried changing from ``match_parent`` to ``wrap_content`` but I'm still getting the same crash

Comment: Allright. Do are you using any other libraries in your project?

Comment: I've got one my own libraries I use for all my projects, the support library and the appcompat support library

Comment: Whats your min and target sdk`? And are you using the latest version jar file?

Comment: My Min is 15 and I'm targeting 21. I think I may have found where the problem lies. I have an app theme in my own library and the manifest sets the theme that is stored in my library. I've taken out my library referene and reverted my theme to the default android theme and now it works

Comment: Which means the issue had nothing to do with the chart library?

Comment: I would assume now, although not sure why it would have this issue as I use this theme in my library in all my apps and never had an issue

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to confirm where the problem is.

I have my apps theme defined in a library that is used by my various other apps, but for some reason when referencing the theme from the library when using MPAndroidChartLib I get this exception. If I copy and paste the theme style from my Library and it to my apps own styles file and reference this instead it works fine.

Comment: I have now removed all kinds of resources from the library and will publish the changes in the next release. Maybe this will fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks, look forward to giving it a try

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it may help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/lineChart1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

The line:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

is important.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately no joy, still getting the same exception

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this exact issue and finally found a working solution.

The clue was an error message on the design preview of the chart fragment:

> The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   
>  charting.charts.LineChart 
>   
>  **Exception Details** 
>   
>  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   
>  com.nineoldandroids.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimatorUpdateListener

Adding `com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+` to my project's build.gradle file fixed the issue:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.5'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+'
compile files('libs/MPChart.jar') 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding lines below in onCreate() did the trick for me

```
getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```